# MAMP PRO 4 - nginx host serves public folder from another disabled apache host

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

So `x.dev` is an nginx host, but shows the public folder which is set on the disabled apache host `a.dev`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was that I forgot that I had switched the ports for apache/nginx and wasn't including that in my url.